# Finding Locator for text

Tags: html

The `xpath` I found for Plan Roles is `By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/h2)` which has other text as well like `Project < Visit < Plan Role`, but I only need to get text of Plan Role.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "abc">
 <html>
 <head>
 <body>
 <div id="errorMsgContainer" class="ui-widget-header"> </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <style>
 <div id="help" class="help">
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div id="header">
 <div id="mainMenu">
 <br clear="all">
 <div class="siteWrapper">
 <div id="content">
  <div id="main" class="main">

   <h2 style="background-color: transparent;">
   <a href="https://abc.com">
   <span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>
   <a href="https://abc.com/test2/1.5/">
  <span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>
  <a href="https://abc.com/test2/1.5/">
   <span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>

      Plan roles

    </h2>
    <ul id="" class="tabPane" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <div class="tabPage">
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">2006-2013 v1.5.0</div>
    </div>
    <script>
    </div>
    <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix  ui-corner-all"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is severely messed up. Unclosed `head`, `style` and `script` tag.

Comment: @BeatAlex :( I know. Can you create locator using the below code.2>
<h2><a href="abcd">
<span style="font-size:9pt;">Projects</span>
</a>
<span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>
<a href= "abcd">
<span style="font-size:9pt;">Test</span>
</a>
<span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>
<a href="abcd">
<span style="font-size:9pt;">Visits</span>
</a>
<span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>
Plan Roles
</h2>

Comment: I cant write code in comments properly, my privileges are limited

Comment: This is the xpath for the element //h2[contains(.,'Projects›Test›Visits›Plan Role')] where Test and Visits are dynamic for different users. I want to get only Plan Role in some variable and compare that variable in another variable value present in excel.